# Last Insert ID on codeigniter with SQL Server returns false

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Good Evening,

I got a problem with the last insert id function with active record codeigniter, it works fine in mysql. But when i try it on SQL Server, the result always return false. Please kindly take a look on my code:

```
function transactions_start($data) {
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $q = $this->db->affected_rows();
    if ($q > 0) {
        return $id;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

this is the result of $this->db->last_query()

```
select @@IDENTITY as id
```

the var_dump() result always returning **bool(false)**.

I'm developing this apps using MySQL and SQL Server, so i need to keep using the active record from codeigniter.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where you define `$this->table`???

Comment: Debug $this->db->insert($this->table, $data); by write 
 $this->db->last_query(); die; after insertion. then see what's the problem. May be your table name is not correct.

Comment: @Saty sorry late answer, i'm defining on the construct function. private $table;

Comment: @UmairHamid okay, i'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The insert_id() function returns the id of last inserted row so you just check whether it is greater than 0 or not. Use it like

```
function transactions_start($data) {
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    if ($id > 0) {
        return $id;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Reference : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: it's returning "String or binary data would be truncated".

Comment: What is the query generated? Use `$this->db->last_query` and post query here